# Show .gif with android.graphics.Movie

Tags: android, animated-gif

I'm trying, create a view with an animated GIF..

When i try run the follow code in emulator all works fine. But when i try run in real Smart Phone, nothing happens..

My view:

```
public class GIFView extends View {

private Movie mMovie;
private long movieStart;

public GIFView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initializeView();
}

public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initializeView();
}

public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initializeView();
}

private void initializeView() {
    InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(
            R.drawable.cookies2);
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (movieStart == 0) {
        movieStart = (int) now;
    }
    if (mMovie != null) {
        int relTime = (int) ((now - movieStart) % mMovie.duration());
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - mMovie.width(), getHeight()
                - mMovie.height());
        this.invalidate();
    }
}}
```

My activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     GIFView gifView = new GIFView(this);
     setContentView(gifView);
}}
```

My Smartphone screenshot:
[image: My Smartphone screenshot]
My emulator screenshot:
[image: My emulator screenshot]

Why my app doesn't run in smartphone?

Comment: Maybe you should try loading your animation through a layout, like this guy here: http://www.android-ever.com/2012/06/android-animated-gif-example.html, in case there is some layout / view info passed? Otherwise your code looks almost the same.

Comment: Thanx @Alex:  your question help us to make work a gif image in android.

Answer (score 22):

Don't turn off hardware acceleration for the whole application.  That's crippling.  Just turn it off for the view:

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Answer (score 13):

I dont think the Movie object works correctly on devices where hardware acceleration is turned on (which is turned on by default in Android 4.x for devices that support it.  Your emulator may not.)

Try adding

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

to the activity definition for MainActivity in AndroidManifest.xml

Example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks! could you please explain what's exactly happening there.

Answer (score 2):

Loading an animated GIF seems tricky, but I would suggest to use a **WebView** as an alternative.

Do as follow to resolve the problem :

1. Copy your GIF in Android Assets.
2. Call webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "", "text/html", "utf-8", null);

I hope it helps !