# How to display .gif file in imageview?

Tags: android, layout, imageview, gif, animated

My layout have lots of imageviews. I want to show .gif animated file in just one imageview. I tried Yash method ([Adding gif image in an ImageView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android)) but .gif file shown all layout. Other views dissappeared.

I want to show all.

Any idea?

Comment: Show us some code, a better description of how it should look (which we may be able to grasp by looking at your xml layout) and a screen cap of how it fails.

Comment: I got solution, refer to this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif/23670399#23670399

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding gif image in an ImageView in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android)

Answer (score 17):

**If you don't want to use Glide,** just add this to your dependencies and create your unique 'gif'. Check for the latest version before use. ImageView:

```
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'
```

Works very efficiently with minimal lines of code. An example is:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dancer"
        android:src="@drawable/maddancer" />
```

Answer (score 10):

> With Third Party Dependency.

Add following dependency to your app gradle file

```
dependencies {
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.17'
```

}

Then after sync your project. When synchronization is done, go to your layout file and add the following code

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/gif_file"/>
```

This is simplest way to display .gif images into imageview you can deal with as normal android ImageView Reference [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35273824/3514144)

> Another way to display .gif into imageview without adding any
> dependency into app gradle file.

Put your .gif file into res/raw folder, in your fragment or activity and than you can set gif in imageview like

```
GifAnimationDrawable gif;
    
    try {
            gif = new 
             GifAnimationDrawable(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.download));
            gif.setOneShot(false);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ivGif.setImageDrawable(gif);
        gif.setVisible(true, true);
    }
```

1)GifAnimationDrawable .java

```
public class GifAnimationDrawable extends AnimationDrawable

    {
        private boolean decoded;
    
    private GifDecoder mGifDecoder;

    private Bitmap mTmpBitmap;

    private int height, width;
    
    public GifAnimationDrawable(File f) throws IOException
    {
        this(f, false);
    }
    
    public GifAnimationDrawable(InputStream is) throws IOException
    {
        this(is, false);
    }
    
    public GifAnimationDrawable(File f, boolean inline) throws IOException
    {
        this(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f), 32768), inline);
    }
    
    public GifAnimationDrawable(InputStream is, boolean inline) throws IOException
    {
        super();
        InputStream bis = is;
        if(!BufferedInputStream.class.isInstance(bis)) bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 32768);
        decoded = false;
        mGifDecoder = new GifDecoder();
        mGifDecoder.read(bis);
        mTmpBitmap = mGifDecoder.getFrame(0);
        android.util.Log.v("GifAnimationDrawable", "===>Lead frame: ["+width+"x"+height+"; "+mGifDecoder.getDelay(0)+";"+mGifDecoder.getLoopCount()+"]");
        height = mTmpBitmap.getHeight();
        width = mTmpBitmap.getWidth();
        addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(mTmpBitmap), mGifDecoder.getDelay(0));
        setOneShot(mGifDecoder.getLoopCount() != 0);
        setVisible(true, true);
        if(inline){
            loader.run();
        }else{
            new Thread(loader).start();
        }
    }
    
    public boolean isDecoded(){ return decoded; }
    
    private Runnable loader = new Runnable(){
        public void run() 
        {
            mGifDecoder.complete();
            int i, n = mGifDecoder.getFrameCount(), t;
            for(i=1;i<n;i++){
                mTmpBitmap = mGifDecoder.getFrame(i);
                t = mGifDecoder.getDelay(i);
                android.util.Log.v("GifAnimationDrawable", "===>Frame "+i+": "+t+"]");
                addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(mTmpBitmap), t);
            }
            decoded = true;
            mGifDecoder = null;
        }
    };
    
    public int getMinimumHeight(){ return height; }
    public int getMinimumWidth(){ return width; }
    public int getIntrinsicHeight(){ return height; }
    public int getIntrinsicWidth(){ return width; }
}
```

2. GifDecoder.java

   public class GifDecoder

   {

   ```
    public static final int STATUS_OK = 0;  
    public static final int STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR = 1;
    public static final int STATUS_OPEN_ERROR = 2;  
    protected static final int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 4096;
    public static final    int MIN_DELAY                   = 100;
    public static final    int MIN_DELAY_ENFORCE_THRESHOLD = 20;
    protected InputStream in;
    protected int status;
    protected int width; // full image width
    protected int height; // full image height
    protected boolean gctFlag; // global color table used
    protected int gctSize; // size of global color table
    protected int loopCount = 1; // iterations; 0 = repeat forever
    protected int[] gct; // global color table
    protected int[] lct; // local color table
    protected int[] act; // active color table
    protected int bgIndex; // background color index
    protected int bgColor; // background color
    protected int lastBgColor; // previous bg color
    protected int pixelAspect; // pixel aspect ratio
    protected boolean lctFlag; // local color table flag
    protected boolean interlace; // interlace flag
    protected int lctSize; // local color table size
    protected int ix, iy, iw, ih; // current image rectangle
    protected int lrx, lry, lrw, lrh;
    protected Bitmap image; // current frame
    protected Bitmap lastBitmap; // previous frame
    protected byte[] block = new byte[256]; // current data block
    protected int blockSize = 0; // block size last graphic control extension info
    protected int dispose = 0; // 0=no action; 1=leave in place; 2=restore to bg; 3=restore to prev
    protected int lastDispose = 0;
    protected boolean transparency = false; // use transparent color
    protected int delay = 0; // delay in milliseconds
    protected int transIndex; // transparent color index
    // LZW decoder working arrays
    protected short[] prefix;
    protected byte[] suffix;
    protected byte[] pixelStack;
    protected byte[] pixels;
    protected Vector<GifFrame> frames; // frames read from current file
    protected int frameCount;

    private boolean readComplete;

    public GifDecoder()
    {
        readComplete = false;
    }

    private static class GifFrame {
        public GifFrame(Bitmap im, int del) {
            image = im;
            delay = del;
        }

        public Bitmap image;
        public int delay;
    }

    /**
     * Gets display duration for specified frame.
     *
     * @param n
     *          int index of frame
     * @return delay in milliseconds
     */
    public int getDelay(int n) {
        delay = -1;
        if ((n >= 0) && (n < frameCount)) {
            delay = frames.elementAt(n).delay;
            //meets browser compatibility standards
            if (delay < MIN_DELAY_ENFORCE_THRESHOLD) delay = MIN_DELAY;
        }
        return delay;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of frames read from file.
     *
     * @return frame count
     */
    public int getFrameCount() {
        return frameCount;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the first (or only) image read.
     *
     * @return BufferedBitmap containing first frame, or null if none.
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return getFrame(0);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the "Netscape" iteration count, if any. A count of 0 means repeat indefinitiely.
     *
     * @return iteration count if one was specified, else 1.
     */
    public int getLoopCount() {
        return loopCount;
    }

    /**
     * Creates new frame image from current data (and previous frames as specified by their disposition codes).
     */
    protected void setPixels() {
        // expose destination image's pixels as int array
        int[] dest = new int[width * height];
        // fill in starting image contents based on last image's dispose code
        if (lastDispose > 0) {
            if (lastDispose == 3) {
                // use image before last
                int n = frameCount - 2;
                if (n > 0) {
                    lastBitmap = getFrame(n - 1);
                } else {
                    lastBitmap = null;
                }
            }
            if (lastBitmap != null) {
                lastBitmap.getPixels(dest, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                // copy pixels
                if (lastDispose == 2) {
                    // fill last image rect area with background color
                    int c = 0;
                    if (!transparency) {
                        c = lastBgColor;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < lrh; i++) {
                        int n1 = (lry + i) * width + lrx;
                        int n2 = n1 + lrw;
                        for (int k = n1; k < n2; k++) {
                            dest[k] = c;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // copy each source line to the appropriate place in the destination
        int pass = 1;
        int inc = 8;
        int iline = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ih; i++) {
            int line = i;
            if (interlace) {
                if (iline >= ih) {
                    pass++;
                    switch (pass) {
                    case 2:
                        iline = 4;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        iline = 2;
                        inc = 4;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        iline = 1;
                        inc = 2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
                line = iline;
                iline += inc;
            }
            line += iy;
            if (line < height) {
                int k = line * width;
                int dx = k + ix; // start of line in dest
                int dlim = dx + iw; // end of dest line
                if ((k + width) < dlim) {
                    dlim = k + width; // past dest edge
                }
                int sx = i * iw; // start of line in source
                while (dx < dlim) {
                    // map color and insert in destination
                    int index = ((int) pixels[sx++]) & 0xff;
                    int c = act[index];
                    if (c != 0) {
                        dest[dx] = c;
                    }
                    dx++;
                }
            }
        }
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest, width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the image contents of frame n.
     *
     * @return BufferedBitmap representation of frame, or null if n is invalid.
     */
    public Bitmap getFrame(int n) {
        if (frameCount <= 0)
            return null;
        n = n % frameCount;
        return ((GifFrame) frames.elementAt(n)).image;
    }

    /**
     * Reads GIF image from stream
     *
     * @param is
     *          containing GIF file.
     * @return read status code (0 = no errors)
     */
    public int read(InputStream is)
    {
        init();
        if (is != null) {
            in = is;
            readHeader();
            if (!err()) {
                readContents();
                if (frameCount < 0) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                }
            }
        } else {
            status = STATUS_OPEN_ERROR;
        }
        readComplete = true;
        return status;
    }

    public void complete()
    {
        readContents();
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Decodes LZW image data into pixel array. Adapted from John Cristy's BitmapMagick.
     */
    protected void decodeBitmapData() {
        int nullCode = -1;
        int npix = iw * ih;
        int available, clear, code_mask, code_size, end_of_information, in_code, old_code, bits, code, count, i, datum, data_size, first, top, bi, pi;
        if ((pixels == null) || (pixels.length < npix)) {
            pixels = new byte[npix]; // allocate new pixel array
        }
        if (prefix == null) {
            prefix = new short[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
        }
        if (suffix == null) {
            suffix = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
        }
        if (pixelStack == null) {
            pixelStack = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE + 1];
        }
        // Initialize GIF data stream decoder.
        data_size = read();
        clear = 1 << data_size;
        end_of_information = clear + 1;
        available = clear + 2;
        old_code = nullCode;
        code_size = data_size + 1;
        code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
        for (code = 0; code < clear; code++) {
            prefix[code] = 0; // XXX ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            suffix[code] = (byte) code;
        }
        // Decode GIF pixel stream.
        datum = bits = count = first = top = pi = bi = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < npix;) {
            if (top == 0) {
                if (bits < code_size) {
                    // Load bytes until there are enough bits for a code.
                    if (count == 0) {
                        // Read a new data block.
                        count = readBlock();
                        if (count <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        bi = 0;
                    }
                    datum += (((int) block[bi]) & 0xff) << bits;
                    bits += 8;
                    bi++;
                    count--;
                    continue;
                }
                // Get the next code.
                code = datum & code_mask;
                datum >>= code_size;
                    bits -= code_size;
                    // Interpret the code
                    if ((code > available) || (code == end_of_information)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (code == clear) {
                        // Reset decoder.
                        code_size = data_size + 1;
                        code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
                        available = clear + 2;
                        old_code = nullCode;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (old_code == nullCode) {
                        pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                        old_code = code;
                        first = code;
                        continue;
                    }
                    in_code = code;
                    if (code == available) {
                        pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                        code = old_code;
                    }
                    while (code > clear) {
                        pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                        code = prefix[code];
                    }
                    first = ((int) suffix[code]) & 0xff;
                    // Add a new string to the string table,
                    if (available >= MAX_STACK_SIZE) {
                        break;
                    }
                    pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                    prefix[available] = (short) old_code;
                    suffix[available] = (byte) first;
                    available++;
                    if (((available & code_mask) == 0) && (available < MAX_STACK_SIZE)) {
                        code_size++;
                        code_mask += available;
                    }
                    old_code = in_code;
            }
            // Pop a pixel off the pixel stack.
            top--;
            pixels[pi++] = pixelStack[top];
            i++;
        }
        for (i = pi; i < npix; i++) {
            pixels[i] = 0; // clear missing pixels
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if an error was encountered during reading/decoding
     */
    protected boolean err() {
        return status != STATUS_OK;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes or re-initializes reader
     */
    protected void init() {
        status = STATUS_OK;
        frameCount = 0;
        frames = new Vector<GifFrame>();
        gct = null;
        lct = null;
    }

    /**
     * Reads a single byte from the input stream.
     */
    protected int read() {
        int curByte = 0;
        try {
            curByte = in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        }
        return curByte;
    }

    /**
     * Reads next variable length block from input.
     *
     * @return number of bytes stored in "buffer"
     */
    protected int readBlock() {
        blockSize = read();
        int n = 0;
        if (blockSize > 0) {
            try {
                int count = 0;
                while (n < blockSize) {
                    count = in.read(block, n, blockSize - n);
                    if (count == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    n += count;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (n < blockSize) {
                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    /**
     * Reads color table as 256 RGB integer values
     *
     * @param ncolors
     *          int number of colors to read
     * @return int array containing 256 colors (packed ARGB with full alpha)
     */
    protected int[] readColorTable(int ncolors) {
        int nbytes = 3 * ncolors;
        int[] tab = null;
        byte[] c = new byte[nbytes];
        int n = 0;
        try {
            n = in.read(c);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (n < nbytes) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        } else {
            tab = new int[256]; // max size to avoid bounds checks
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (i < ncolors) {
                int r = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                int g = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                int b = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                tab[i++] = 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            }
        }
        return tab;
    }

    /**
     * Main file parser. Reads GIF content blocks.
     */
    protected void readContents() {
        // read GIF file content blocks
        boolean done = false;
        while (!(done || err())) {
            int code = read();
            switch (code) {
            case 0x2C: // image separator
            readBitmap();
            if(!readComplete) return;
            break;
            case 0x21: // extension
                code = read();
                switch (code) {
                case 0xf9: // graphics control extension
                    readGraphicControlExt();
                    break;
                case 0xff: // application extension
                    readBlock();
                    String app = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                        app += (char) block[i];
                    }
                    if (app.equals("NETSCAPE2.0")) {
                        readNetscapeExt();
                    } else {
                        skip(); // don't care
                    }
                    break;
                case 0xfe:// comment extension
                    skip();
                    break;
                case 0x01:// plain text extension
                    skip();
                    break;
                default: // uninteresting extension
                    skip();
                }
                break;
            case 0x3b: // terminator
                done = true;
                break;
            case 0x00: // bad byte, but keep going and see what happens break;
            default:
                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads Graphics Control Extension values
     */
    protected void readGraphicControlExt() {
        read(); // block size
        int packed = read(); // packed fields
        dispose = (packed & 0x1c) >> 2; // disposal method
                    if (dispose == 0) {
                        dispose = 1; // elect to keep old image if discretionary
                    }
                    transparency = (packed & 1) != 0;
                    delay = readShort() * 10; // delay in milliseconds
                    transIndex = read(); // transparent color index
                    read(); // block terminator
    }

    /**
     * Reads GIF file header information.
     */
    protected void readHeader() {
        String id = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            id += (char) read();
        }
        if (!id.startsWith("GIF")) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            return;
        }
        readLSD();
        if (gctFlag && !err()) {
            gct = readColorTable(gctSize);
            bgColor = gct[bgIndex];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads next frame image
     */
    protected void readBitmap() {
        ix = readShort(); // (sub)image position & size
        iy = readShort();
        iw = readShort();
        ih = readShort();
        int packed = read();
        lctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 - local color table flag interlace
        lctSize = (int) Math.pow(2, (packed & 0x07) + 1);
        // 3 - sort flag
        // 4-5 - reserved lctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 - local color
        // table size
        interlace = (packed & 0x40) != 0;
        if (lctFlag) {
            lct = readColorTable(lctSize); // read table
            act = lct; // make local table active
        } else {
            act = gct; // make global table active
            if (bgIndex == transIndex) {
                bgColor = 0;
            }
        }
        int save = 0;
        if (transparency) {
            save = act[transIndex];
            act[transIndex] = 0; // set transparent color if specified
        }
        if (act == null) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR; // no color table defined
        }
        if (err()) {
            return;
        }
        decodeBitmapData(); // decode pixel data
        skip();
        if (err()) {
            return;
        }
        frameCount++;
        // create new image to receive frame data
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
        setPixels(); // transfer pixel data to image
        frames.addElement(new GifFrame(image, delay)); // add image to frame
        // list
        if (transparency) {
            act[transIndex] = save;
        }
        resetFrame();
    }

    /**
     * Reads Logical Screen Descriptor
     */
    protected void readLSD() {
        // logical screen size
        width = readShort();
        height = readShort();
        // packed fields
        int packed = read();
        gctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 : global color table flag
        // 2-4 : color resolution
        // 5 : gct sort flag
        gctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 : gct size
        bgIndex = read(); // background color index
        pixelAspect = read(); // pixel aspect ratio
    }

    /**
     * Reads Netscape extenstion to obtain iteration count
     */
    protected void readNetscapeExt() {
        do {
            readBlock();
            if (block[0] == 1) {
                // loop count sub-block
                int b1 = ((int) block[1]) & 0xff;
                int b2 = ((int) block[2]) & 0xff;
                loopCount = (b2 << 8) | b1;
            }
        } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }

    /**
     * Reads next 16-bit value, LSB first
     */
    protected int readShort() {
        // read 16-bit value, LSB first
        return read() | (read() << 8);
    }

    /**
     * Resets frame state for reading next image.
     */
    protected void resetFrame() {
        lastDispose = dispose;
        lrx = ix;
        lry = iy;
        lrw = iw;
        lrh = ih;
        lastBitmap = image;
        lastBgColor = bgColor;
        dispose = 0;
        transparency = false;
        delay = 0;
        lct = null;
    }

    /**
     * Skips variable length blocks up to and including next zero length block.
     */
    protected void skip() {
        do {
            readBlock();
        } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }
   ```

   }

you can  download the class from    https://github.com/Hipmob/gifanimateddrawable/blob/master/src/com/hipmob/gifanimationdrawable/GifAnimationDrawable.java
**404 Not Found**
https://gist.github.com/devunwired/4479231
**404 Not Found**

If the any above link is not open you can find the class from below link

hope this will save someones time lot because i admire from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736861/3514144 but i want to show it in imageview

As well if link is unavailable you can find class from Github too.Also if you found any problem leave a comment to this answer i'll try best to help :)

**Edit: 12-12-2019**

Another way to load gif in custom imageview use this [library](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)

Comment: Dude, this should be on github, it worked better than Glide and Fresco - do i have your permission to create a small 3rd party lib for it?

Comment: @royiby Please share the link to the library if you have created.

Comment: @Ajay Pandya, can you please share link to downlaod those 2 classes, given dropbox links are not working

Comment: @Ajay GifAnimationDrawable file is not there. Please help

Comment: check link whichi is provided at last in my answer

Answer (score 5):

Or you can simply add WebView to your xml and load the gif image inside the webview. You donot need to do anything else. The image will loop automatically inside the webview

Answer (score 5):

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is the best solution ever. Simply use this code

```
String gifUrl = "http://part/to/your/gifFile.gif";
Glide  
.with( context )
.load( gifUrl )
.into( imageViewGif );
```

Answer (score 5):

Best and easiest solution to display GIF image in Android
and it will work perfectly:

- Open build.gradle (Module: app)
- put in dependencies: 
  compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
- Open layout folder and put this code where you want to display GIF image:
  e-g activity_main.xml

  ```
   <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_gif_file_name"/>
  ```
- android:src="@drawable/your_gif_file_name", Replace 'your_gif_file_name' with your desired gif image file

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately a gif will not animation inside of an ImageView on its own.  You will have to create a new subclass of View to handle this for you.

[Show .gif with android.graphics.Movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482415/show-gif-with-android-graphics-movie)

Answer (score 3):

Use Glide(https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

```
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageview);

        Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.mygif).into(imageViewTarget);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the Fresco library.

https://github.com/facebook/fresco