# How create continuous Animation?

Tags: android, animation

I want to create animation like this to ImageView[image]

Comment: and what have you done so far?

Comment: Use [AnimatorSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29488519/3514144

Comment: @Pallavi Tapkir do u have gif file animation photoframes  ?photoframes code: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/frame-animations-in-android/   If it z gif:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that GIF image  and load that image into Imageview. You can use this library for loading [koral--/android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)

and change your ImageView into

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/src_anim"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_anim"
    />
```

Comment: I solved problem using this

        GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.up_arrow).into(imageViewTarget);

Comment: There are no.of libraries available for GIF